# SQL query across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have only a very basic knowledge of SQL, so pls do forgive if this is a stupid Q. I hunted the internet but could not get an answer.

I have three tables:

> ### title
>
> id int <- PK
>
> artist_id int
>
> album_id int
>
> desc varchar
>
> ### artist
>
> arist_id int      <- FK
>
> desc varchar
>
> ### album
>
> album_id int      <- FK
>
> desc varchar

---

> ### title data
>
> 1, 1, 1, "Give me everything"
>
> 1, 2, 2, "More"
>
> 1, 3, 3, "What makes you beautiful"
>
> ### artist data
>
> 1, "Pitbull"
>
> 2, "Usher"
>
> 3, "One Direction"
>
> ### album data
>
> 1, "Planet Pit"
>
> 2, "More"
>
> 3, "Up All Night"

If I want to do a search of one table I do like so:

> select * from artist where desc like '%direction%';

My objective is to do a search across three tables. The search SQL query should return rows for "title" table where the search criteria has been met in the "desc" field of any of the three tables using the artist_id and album_id fields (which are the linking keys).

My brain is totally muddled today. If the Q is not clear, pls do ask for clarity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple SQL Select from 2 Tables (What is a Join?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040587/simple-sql-select-from-2-tables-what-is-a-join)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a `inner join` between tables like this:

```
select t.* from title t
inner join artist ar on ar.artist_id = t.artist_id
inner join album al on al.album_id = t.album_id
where (t.desc like '%direction%' or ar.desc like '%direction%' or al.desc like '%direction%')
```

Comment: Just back from weekend, so sorry for the delay. Wow! Tried your query and it just worked straight off. Thx aF.